# string value is blank then don't use in condition

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-ui-automation

```
private string FindValue(AutomationElement f_Element)
{
    object l_PriorityFirstValue = GetValue(0);
    object l_PrioritySecondValue= GetValue(1);
    object l_PriorityThirdValue GetValue(2);       

    AutomationElementCollection elementCollection =
        AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition("1", l_PriorityFirstValue));

    if(elementCollection.count==1)
    {
       return "True";
    }
    else
    {
       ////Now try to find with additional call
        elementCollection = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree,
            new AndCondition(
                new PropertyCondition(1, l_PriorityFirstValue),
                new PropertyCondition(2, l_PrioritySecondValue)));

        if (elementCollection.Count == 1)
        {
            return "True";
        }
        else
        {
            ////Now try to find with additional call 
            elementCollection = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree,
                new AndCondition(
                    new PropertyCondition(1, l_PriorityFirstValue),
                    new PropertyCondition(2, l_PrioritySecondValue),
                    new PropertyCondition(3, l_PriorityThirdValue)));

            if (elementCollection.Count == 1)
            {
                return "True";
            }
            else
            {
                 return "false";
            }
        }
    }        
}

private string GetValue(int i)
{
    //get value using parameter i from db.
}
```

I have above code, I don't want to use `Priority` value in condition if it's empty.

For example: suppose `l_PrioritySecondValue` is getting empty, then i don't want to use `new PropertyCondition(2, l_PrioritySecondValue)` in query.

What should be logic in this case? `Priority` value is dynamic. Any value will get empty, first, second or third.

Comment: how?? . will use in this case

Comment: I meant the question text. We fixed it for you, but please use proper punctuation. It's much easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

// This first piece of code is your choice want to do it or not but its easier to make list to pass for the second function

```
 List<Object> PriorityConditions=new List<Object>();    
 for(int i=0;i<LengthOfPriorities(3 in your case);i++)
  {
    PriorityConditions.Add(GetValue(i));
  }
```

Write a functions to get conditions  (ReturnType : AndCondition accept the list of items same )

```
     List<ReturnType> GetConditions(PriorityConditions)
       {
        List<ReturnType> conditions=new List<ReturnType>();
        for(int i=0;i<PriorityConditions.count;i++)
        {
            if(!PriorityConditions[i])   // Check conditions valid for your object (null or empty)
                conditions.Add(PriorityConditions[i]);          
        }

        return conditions;
  }
```

This piece of code will change into this

```
 elementCollection = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree,
            new AndCondition(GetConditions(PriorityConditions)));
```